How To Impose Boundary Condition on a Chain of Quantum Critical Pott's Model By Using Boundary CFT States?
Recently I was reading John Cardy's famous paper on
Boundary conditions, fusion rules and the Verlinde formula
and in section 4.2 where it discussed about 3-state Pott's model, it showed six boundary states.
Suppose there is a finite one dimensional chain of quantum Pott's model which is in it's critical phase. Then obviously this system corresponds to a CFT with $c=\frac{4}{5}$.
My question is that how can I impose boundary conditions on this chain to retain different boundary states which  derived by Cardy?
